# ajax request won't sent whole query

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have this ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/tracks/tweetaction?id=" + $("#artist_id").val() + "&link=" + url + "&message=" + prepopulated_tweet ,
    success: function (data) {
      getPageLink(url);
    }
  });
```

the problem is with the prepopulated_tweet. for some reason instead of sending this

> @Myrfriends @RndomPerson "you'll love this track" @Krilex - Pieces -
>   Red #Rock #Pop #Soul Krilex.****.co/rx11

it sends this

> @Myrfriends @RndomPerson \"you'll love this track\" @Krilex - Pieces -
>   Red

request is like this

```
Started GET "/tracks/tweetaction?id=1&link=http://localhost:3000/artists/1?refid=3d4e1145-7d02-42a0-87f0-aa5f992dfe9b&trackid=1
&message=@Myrfriends%20@RndomPerson%20%22you%27ll%20love%20this%20track%22%20@Krilex%20-%20Pieces%20-%20Red"
```

whats wrong here?

Comment: Certain symbols have special meaning in URLs. For instance, #. This is the reason why it is breaking your URL.

Comment: figured it just now cheers @EddeAlmeida

Answer (score 2):

doing this seem to fix my problem

`prepopulated_tweet = encodeURIComponent(prepopulated_tweet)`

Comment: Exactly. This encodes your string as a correct URL.